# Receiving NodaTime.LocalTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, .net, nodatime

I keep getting the error `Cannot convert value to NodaTime.LocalTime`, and I can't seem to find anyone else with the problem. I also can't find in the documentation how I can do this.

An example of what I'm trying to send is;

```json
{
   "time": "22:00"
}
```

Is something wrong with this format? As far as I'm aware, `NodaTime.LocalTime` is formatted exactly like this. I know a similar problem exists for the date object, but it really doesn't apply to this, as it has no `Z` at the end of the string. I also tried taking the semi-colon out of the string I send, but that didn't do anything.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your json is invalid, pls fix it according this example

```
using NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet;

var d = new Data { time = NodaTime.LocalTime.Noon };

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d);
```

output

```
{"time":"12:00:00"}
```

So your json should be

```
var json =  @"{
   ""time"": ""22:00:00""
}";

Data data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);
```

everything is working properly in this case

class

```
public class Data
{
    public LocalTime time { get; set; }
}
```